# Lunajson not found in lua 5.2.3

Tags: json, lua

I have installed lunajson with luarocks.  When I attempt to use the module I keep getting the error below.  I am just trying to decode a website that responds back with some json.
The OS is running Debian Jessie.  I know it is an older OS and I will eventually update it, but this should not cause my issue.

https://somedudesays.com/2019/12/using-json-with-lua/

```
lua:10: module 'lunajson' not found:
        no field package.preload['lunajson']
        no file '/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts/lunajson.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/lunajson.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/lunajson.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/lunajson.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
        no file './lunajson.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359102/6632736.